# Help required. The amplitude of Compton scattering after exchanging external photons do not match with textbooks

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams

Consider the two tree-level Feynman diagrams for Compton scattering as shown below. The time is taken to run from left to right.

[image]

I am confused about a simple thing that is supposed to be very trivial. The Feynman amplitude corresponding to the diagram on the left is
$$iM_a=\left[\bar{u}(k_2)\epsilon^*_{\mu}(p_2)(ie\gamma^\mu)\frac{i}{(\not{p}_1+\not{k}_1-m_e)}(ie\gamma^\nu)\bar{u}(k_1)\epsilon_{\nu}(p_1)\right]\\
~~~~~~~~~=\left[\bar{u}(k_2)(ie\gamma^\mu)\frac{i}{(\not{p}_1+\not{k}_1-m_e)}(ie\gamma^\nu)\bar{u}(k_1)\right]\epsilon^*_{\mu}(p_2)\epsilon_{\nu}(p_1).$$
Similarly, the amplitude of the diagram on the right is
$$iM_b=\left[\bar{u}(k_2)\color{red}{\epsilon^*_{\mu}(p_1)}(ie\gamma^\mu)\frac{i}{(-\not{p}_2+\not{k}_1-m_e)}(ie\gamma^\nu)\bar{u}(k_1)\color{red}{\epsilon_{\nu}(p_2)}\right]\\
~~~~~~~~~=\left[\bar{u}(k_2)(ie\gamma^\mu)\frac{i}{(-\not{p}_2+\not{k}_1-m_e)}(ie\gamma^\nu)\bar{u}(k_1)\right]\color{red}{\epsilon^*_{\mu}(p_1)\epsilon_{\nu}(p_2)}$$

I get the first amplitude correct by applying the Feynman rules.

But for the second amplitude (i.e. after exchanging the photons) as written above does not agree with textbooks (say, Peskin & Schroeder, page 158). So I must have made some silly mistake. In particular, the red-colored parts of the second amplitude do not match. They get $\color{blue}{\epsilon^*_{\mu}(p_2)\epsilon_{\nu}(p_1)}$ in place of $\color{red}{\epsilon^*_{\mu}(p_1)\epsilon_{\nu}(p_2)}$. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you are getting and how it differs from the correct answer? I'm not exactly sure what the red text is supposed to denote.

Comment: @NiharKarve As opposed to what I have written for the second amplitude $iM_b$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ (or $p_1$ and $p_2$) are interchanged in the textbooks i.e. the photon parts are the same for both $M_a$ and $M_b$, in textbooks. Thanks, I have added it now in the question.

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Comment: Thanks, added that.

Comment: But have you tried calculating $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ to see if there really is a difference in yours vs the text?